# Altium Designer New Template

Tags: schematics, altium

I have just prepared a new template for Altium Designer schematics. I included an image to template. My question is that if i prepare a project with this template, how can i embed this image when i need to send another person? Because after i sent a project with my new template, i realized that the template image could not be seen on an another computer (It wrote on template as "Cannot open file C:...) I have some examples which are embedded for these situations however i don't know how i can do. This photo shows when i sent to another computer:

[image: New Altium Template on Another Computer]

Comment: Try asking the question on live.altium.com

Comment: I could not register there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double click image to get to properties. Click "embedded."  You should do this in the actual .SchDot template file, it's not clickable once the template is instantiated.